# Unable to open excel file created inthe python code

Tags: python, excel, csv

I converted a few .csv files using python code to .xls but now when i try to open the files it gives me an error : "COUNT_DIST2.xls cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupt, located on a server that is not responding , or read only". 
I have created many other files in this projects which are both .csv and .xls but none of them are giving me this problem. I think in my code somewhere maybe i am doing something wrong. I am very sure this is not a network error or office error because i am able to open all the other documents.

Attached is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xlwt
import os
path = ('C:\Users\PETERemote\PycharmProjects\untitled\distributions')
data = []
count =1
count2 = 0
for files in os.listdir(path):
    if files.endswith("COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count*1) + ".csv"):
        count += 1
count2 = count-2
print(count2)
#print(count2 = count)

count3=1
file_name = "COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count3*1) + ".csv"
while (count3<=count2):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append([word for word in line.split("  ") if word])
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    output_file = open("COUNT16_DIST" + str(count3 * 1) + ".xls", 'w')
    count3 += 1
    sheet = wb.add_sheet("Sheet1")
    for row_index in range(len(data)):
        for col_index in range(len(data[row_index])):
            sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index][col_index])
    wb.save(output_file)
    data = []
    output_file.close()
```

Comment: Why don't you use xlsx instead?

Comment: I just tried xlsx.  the error i see is : excel cannot open the file because the format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file name has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Comment: Are u trying to open the file via python or excel?

Comment: Once the excel is created i manually go to the location to open it and it gives the error. However i also have to use these excel files in the other function as well and at this point i can't.

Comment: Strange thing, I haven't faced anything like this though I have used linux servers

Comment: Hey @aps_s : I too am facing the same issue. How could you get to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using xlsxwriter:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

FYI, there is also a package called openpyxl, that can read/write Excel
xlsx/xlsm files which I have tested it and it's working fine.

Comment: This is very nice but I am just curious: Is it possible make this code a little more neat by placing a "with open(Excelfile, 'w', encoding='utf8') as w: [do: write into Excel]" sort of code inside the existing "with open()" statement?